# Whats the use of read - write .code/.text segment?

Tags: c, embedded

My understanding is that .code/.text segment of the object file is for storing instructions & literals and should be read only, as they are not supposed to be changed while run time. But, I came across a source file ([flash memory driver of STM32 HAL Library](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeG0/blob/master/Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_flash.c)) which when compiled occupies some read - write code segment (68 bytes). I got the memory listing & mapping information from the project map file generated by the IAR EWARM IDE.

Whats the potential use of read - write code memory segment? & What causes the placement of instructions in this segment?

Comment: I can't be arsed to read 700 LoC to find what you are talking about, let alone a whole Github project. But generally flash programming algorithms cannot execute out of flash, or you'd cut off the branch you are sitting on so to speak. It is therefore common to execute the flash programming driver out of data flash or RAM instead. You need a specialized linker segment to hold the code for it.

Comment: Thanks  @Lundin. Do you have/recommend any sources/books that can help lead me to more information about this topic.

Comment: I guess it is the `static __RAM_FUNC void FLASH_Program_Fast(uint32_t Address, uint32_t DataAddress)` that is in RAM? That's probably because code cannot execute in flash while the flash is being programmed.

Comment: @tonyjosi If you are lucky there's some app notes about it for your specific MCU (look for bootloader app notes etc). Otherwise it's your MCU manual. In some cases you have several flash banks and then you can load a duplicate of the flash driver in each bank and execute out of the one you aren't programming.

Comment: The dirty hack version would be to write the driver in C, come up with some easy to call interface with as few parameters as possible (void func (void) etc), disassemble, double check calling convention. Then chop up the disassembly into op code hex, store it in an array and then wildly cast the array address to a function pointer type and call it. Done that too, it ain't pretty or fun to maintain. The best method is always to execute the flash driver out of NVM such as data flash.

Comment: The comments on the necessity of functions in RAM while flashing are correct. But it is just a sign of lazyness to re-use a predefined section attribute for this if there is no need to modify the contents. They could have defined an own section in RAM but with read-execute-only flags. -- Anyway, I can think of use cases where you need to modify the machine code during run-time. From personal experience, some Gameboy games do this for speed.

Comment: @thebusybee `have defined an own section in RAM but with read-execute-only flags.` what for if it is in the fact RW memory and library like HAL should not touch MPU (if present) on bare metal uC systems.` Having misleading declarations is a very bad practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whats the potential use of read - write code memory segment?

There are many reason but two are the most important.

1. You cant program the flash segment you run the code from. You need to execute it from RAM
2. SRAM is 0WS memory. Very often if the latency of the interrupt handler is important it is placed in SRAM memory. Many STM32 uC have TCM memory having direct bus to core. Some of them have even ITCM & DTCM tightly coupled with the core instruction & data buses allowing parallel instruction fetch and data access.

> What causes the placement of instructions in this segment?

It is a startup code which copies it from FLASH to RAM. This segment is RW because SRAM is RW. The code will copy the data from the FLASH to SRAM. Your code may later (if the uC has MPU) protect this area, but from the linker script point of view this area is RW.